# Failed to run maven install?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Hi a query I have configured my pom.xml, was downloaded all libraries except the library jdbc6 Oracle 11.2.0, so for now I've had to say, I do not understand why not download this library. My pom.xml is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.bbva.sca</groupId>
    <artifactId>adm</artifactId>
    <name>AdmSCA</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-release</id>
            <name>Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>jboss Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ibilio maven-2</id>
            <name>ibilio Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>primefaces-repo</id>
            <name>Primefaces Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>oracle</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Bundle Releases</name>
            <url>http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ibilio maven-1</id>
            <name>ibilio Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/1</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- JSF -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
            <version>3.5</version>  
        </dependency>
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>  
            <artifactId>redmond</artifactId>  
            <version>1.0.9</version>  
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

While cleaning out my maven satisfactory, but when installing I get this error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AdmSCA 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ adm ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ adm ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 62 source files to C:\Users\PC\Documents\BBVA\Versiones\AdmSCA\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.044s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Sep 28 22:08:13 COT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project adm: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_34\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: do you have java installed ?

Comment: point maven to JDK, not JRE.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a JDK instead of, or in addition to, a JRE, and set up your JAVA_HOME to point to the JDK accordingly.

As per the [Maven installation instructions](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation_Instructions):

> Maven is a Java tool, so you must have Java installed in order to proceed. More precisely, you need a Java Development Kit (JDK), the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) is not sufficient.

Further to that:

> make sure that `JAVA_HOME` exists in your user variables or in the system variables and it is set to the location of your JDK, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_02`

And slightly off-topic:

> and [make sure] that `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` is in your `Path` environment variable

Comment: To put it simply, compiling Java code requires a Java compiler, and a JRE does not include a Java compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This exception is because "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_34..\lib\tools.jar " ,

as tools.jar is available in JDK not with JRE.

If you are trying to use embedded mavan like in eclipse you need to update the installed JREs for eclipse with JDK installed directories

go to the below options in eclipse

windows--> preferences --> java --> installed JREs and click on add then locate the JDK installed directory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two questions.

1. Why no jdbc6 jar > Oracle jar is not available on Maven central repository. This is a proprietory file which you need to download from oracle site or get from your DBA team. Then you can install the jar file manually in your local repository. Refer http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html
2. You need to run your maven with JDK and not JRE. If you are running from command prompt, you need to set JAVA_HOME to the JDK path. If you are running maven from some form of IDE, you need to set the Maven environment accordingly.